# Importing data and comparing to string-defined field

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

A CSV import  needs to compare a column of data to an indexed string value which are number literals:

The import_csv task

```
   @model = row[0]
   @article =  Article.where(['model = ?', @model.to_i]).first
```

is thus attempting to compare the integer from the csv file to a string ad returning.

```
LINE 1: ...T  "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE (model = 1410) LI...
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE (model = 1406) LIMIT 1'
01406, ,0,0,1,0,0,RASATO,,408
Error importing row because 'PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
```

*Note:*  comparing string on string

```
   @article =  Article.where(['model = ?', @model]).first
```

`'Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id'`

Is there any way of effecting the comparison, short of saving an indexed value of the string-defined variable?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message: `operator does not exist: character varying = integer` -- I can assume that `model` column has type String. So you have to compare it to a string, not integer.

Try:

```
@article =  Article.where(['model = ?', @model.to_s]).first
```

or perform any additional processing on `@model` but eventually convert it to String before passing to `.where`.

**UPDATE**: Also, why would you use the bind params syntax for `where` for such a simple case? Pass a hash, like so:

```
Article.where(model: @model)
```

This way ActiveRecord will perform all necessary type casting.

Comment: unfortunately, that returns `'Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id'`

Comment: These two seem unconnected. Now that ActiveRecord builds correct SQL, you have some other problem. A stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: I'm decoded to store a `to_i` version of the string.  Slightly more work, but solving the issue upstream feels cleaner.